# C# Generating Classes from XSD

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I need to use a third party web service who kindly provide .xsd schema files defining the xml messages that need to be sent. I've ran the xsd.exe tool to generate the classes so I can work with actual objects that I can then serialise into the messages that need to be sent.

The classes that are generated however are extremely verbose, there are no constructors and each nested object have very long names. The .cs file it generated for one .xsd schema has over 3000 lines of code and 35 partial classes.

So my question is am I right in generating these classes then just making do with the code it produces? Is there a better way to generate this xml other than hand coding my own version of the classes that serialise to the correct format?

I've not had a lot of experience with working with .xsd files so dont really know what the best course of action is.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking into xsd2code from http://xsd2code.codeplex.com/. It has features that might better suit your needs